# How can I send an email by Java application using Gmail, Now google has disabled the settings for less secure app

Tags: spring-boot, smtp, gmail

From May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

Now if I am trying to send email from my application with Gmail, its throwing folowing error

> org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Does anyone know how to implement this now?

I tried searching over an internet the ways to do this but did not get any soution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the two factors authentication on you google account.
Then you will be able to generate a username and password to use it for sending emails.

Click on you profile icon -> Manage your google account -> Security (on the left menu) -> Signing in to Google (it is big enough to see it lol) -> You need to setup two factors authentication -> you should be able to generate an app and google will provide you a username and password -> use them for your java mail configuration